# Using android.os.FileObserver to watch "\data" directory not working

Tags: android, filesystemwatcher

I set up a test program to learn more about FileObserver in android SDK (2.2).
It seems to work fine when FileObserver is set up to watch "/mnt/sdcard".  The onEvent() function gets called when some file system changes occur inside "/mnt/sdcard".
However, if I change FileObserver to watch "/data", the onEvent() function no longer gets called even when I make file system changes in "/data".

Thanks in advance for any comments or answers.

Comment: Were you intending to watch the **/mnt** directory itself for creation/deletion of files?

Comment: It's been a while so I can't remember exactly what I was doing. But most likely no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have read access to the whole of `/data`, so I am not surprised that `FileObserver` does not work for it.

Try using `FileObserver` with a more narrow scope (e.g., your own `getFilesDir()`) to which you have read access.

Comment: Thanks.  I was guessing directory permissions might have something to do it, but I wasn't sure.  My test android app certainly didn't run under a root account.  It ran under an account called app_68 (uid = 10068).  If I use "adb.exe shell" to gain root access, can I give app_68 root access as well?  If so, will the FileObserver in my test app be able to watch all file system changes inside "/data"?

Comment: It's indeed a directory permission problem.  I changed the directory permission of "/data" for everyone to "rwx" and the FileObserver's onEvent() gets called now when watching "/data".  Thanks for the help, CommonsWare.