# implementing a crossplatform filesystemwatcher with mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm interested in implementing a crossplatform filesystemwatcher in the PCL core if possible.  What general approach do you recommend within the context of mvvmcross?  My first thought was to get the different device file systems through the file-plugin, then setup a `while` loop but it sounds painfully inefficient:

```
while (!File.Exist)
{
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
//do stuff
```

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which platforms you are targeting, some platforms do support File watchers - e.g. Android has a `FileObserver` class (eg. see [Using android.os.FileObserver to watch "\data" directory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508231/using-android-os-fileobserver-to-watch-data-directory-not-working))

On the platforms which don't have a native file system watcher, then I guess some kind of timed check is the best you can do. In general, I would recommend using some kind of `Timer` rather than a `Thread.Sleep` - mainly because `Timer` is generally more memory efficient but also because `Thread.Sleep` isn't available in PCLs.

For platforms like iOS and WP which sandbox the file system access for each app, then I suspect actually implementing a file system watcher isn't necessary - since your app is the only app which can read or write to your app's file system, then you should have an easier way to work out when the file system contents change.

Answer (score 0):

A common  miss-conception with File.Exists is that it checks that a file exists....

What it actually checks for is, is the file accessible to you. So if the file was on a share and you didn't have the correct permissions it may return false.

I guess this may vary from platform to platform so watch out.